# Rendering an object passed through Pusher in Rails

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby, pusher

I am trying to implement a realtime chat application.

I'm using pusher to notify server about the button click, and then pass the message object as **message** to a subscriber. What I need to do is, render that message in other user's chat screen(show.html.erb) dynamically. Here is my cycle:

```
// MessagesController.rb

    def create
        conversation = Conversation.find(params[:conversation_id])
    message = Message.create(content: params[:content], user_id: params[:user_id])
    conversation.messages << message
        Pusher['test_channel'].trigger('my_event', {
      message: message
    })
    end
```

And my subscriber is

```
// show.html.erb    
    // some html code 
       <ul class="chats">
       <%= render @messages %>
       </ul>
    // some html code

    <script>
         // some js code
         var channel = pusher.subscribe('some_channel');

         channel.bind('some_event', function(data) {
             // What to do here?
         });
    </script>
```

Comment: What do you /want/ to do there?

Comment: @DickieBoy I have a _message.html.erb partial. What I want to do is, render the message that is passed from from MessageController create function. I have tried `$('.chats').append('<%= render(@message)')` and its variations, but these does not seem to be helping.

Comment: `@message` wont be available. You probably want to do some sort of ajax call to the a view that renders a single message(rather than a collection). Or build the template using something like ich.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This assumes you are using jquery. It's also untested so may have a few bugs/syntax errors.

Ajax method:

JS

```
channel.bind('some_event', function(data) {
  $.ajax({
    url:'/messages/'+data.message.id,
    success:function(html){ $('.chats').append(html)}
  });
});
```

routes:

```
match '/messages/:id' => "messages#show_no_layout"
```

controller:

```
def show_no_layout
  @message = Message.find(params[:id])
  render "show", layout: false
end
```

view(show.html.erb):

```
<%= *whatever you want in here* %>
```

ICH([read more](http://icanhazjs.com/)) method:

This will of course require adding an extra js file which is why its not my first suggestion.

Template:

```
<script id = "messageTemplate" type = "text/html">
   {{ message.content }}
   // plus whatever else you want.
</script>

channel.bind('some_event', function(data) {
  messageHtml = ich.messageTemplate(data.message);
  $('.chats').append(messageHtml);
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I didn't know that I could do ajax requests with remote: => true parameter in a form, so I have just switched to it. If it does not work, gonna try yours again.

Comment: Remote true is an excellent option, I should have mentioned it.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using JQuery,

```
channel.bind('some_event', function(data) {
    $('.message').text(data.message);
});
```

See this [tutorial](https://pusher.com/tutorials/realtime-notifications).